# Qubit passing through quantum gate animation

Tags: graphics, animation, physics, text

I have the following code:

```
Animate[
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick,Black}],FaceForm[White],Rectangle[{0,0}],
     Circle[{a,0.5},0.1],
     Black,Text["|0>",{a,0.5}],Large,Text["X",{0.5,0.5}]}],{a,-2,-0.1,0.15}]
```

I am trying to create a program where the circle, labeled |0$\rangle$ goes to the box, labeled X (points if you can make the X a decent size), disappears as it goes through, and comes out labeled |1$\rangle$. The current animation has it going up right to the edge of the box, but I can't figure out how to make it disappear and switch labels as it goes through it. I'd like to end up exporting this (though I can put it into `Table` format myself) as an animated gif that I can put into a video.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding ⟩: esc+>+esc

Comment: @corey979, I see, thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
Animate[
  Graphics[
    { FaceForm[White]
    , EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}]
    , {Gray, Line[{{-12, 0}, {12, 0}}]}
    , Disk[{t, 0}, 2]
    , Text[Style[If[t < 0, "|0〉", "|1〉"], 32], {t, 0}]
    , Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}]
    , Text[Style["X", 64], {0, 0}]
    }
  , PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, Automatic}
  ]
, {t, -10, 10}
]
```

[image: animated qubit]

The key to making the qubit disappear behind the gate is to ensure that the `Rectangle` is opaque and drawn after the `Disk` is drawn (i.e. the rectangle appears later in the list of `Graphics` directives than the disk).  The label change is accomplished by the `If` expression which evaluates to |0〉 prior to time zero and |1〉 thereafter.  Finally, the unsightly resizing of the graphic is prevented by explicitly specifying the left and right edges of the plot range.

Comment: I'll leave here another way to implement the transitioning qubit: ``Text[Style[StringForm["|`1`〉", Boole[t >= 0]], 32], {t, 0}]``.

Answer (score 9):

Going off WReach's clever transition, here are a couple of alternative transitions. These transitions all have a sort of "sharpness" parameter, so I've put them in a `Manipulate` and you can let the time play and adjust the parameter as you wish. Mix and match them as you please (and remember that the order in which the `Graphics` elements are drawn matters)!

## Fade

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Thick, Opacity[Abs[opacityfactor*t]], Circle[{t, 0}, 2],
   Text[Style[
     If[t < 0, "|0〉", "|1〉"], 
     32], {t, 0}],
   Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[White], 
   Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}], Text[Style["X", 64]]
   }, PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, Automatic}]
 , {t, -10, 10}, {{opacityfactor, .1}, .05, .3}]
```

[image: fade transition]

## Highlight

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Thick, Circle[{t, 0}, 2], 
   Style[Circle[{t, 0}, Max[Abs[1.5*t], 2]], Red, Thick, 
    Opacity[If[Abs[t] < cutoff, 1, 0]]],
   Text[Style[
     If[t < 0, "|0〉", "|1〉"], 
     32], {t, 0}],
   Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[White], 
   Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}], Text[Style["X", 64]]
   }, PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-5, 5}}]
 , {t, -10, 10}, {{cutoff, 4}, 1, 6}]
```

[image: highlight transition]

### Exporting

And for your convenience, here are the exportable commands:

#### Fade

```
opacityfactor = .1;
fade = Table[
   Graphics[{
     Thick, Opacity[Abs[opacityfactor*t]], Circle[{t, 0}, 2],
     Text[
      Style[If[t < 0, "|0〉", 
        "|1〉"], 32], {t, 0}],
     Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[White], 
     Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}], Text[Style["X", 64]]
     }, PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, Automatic}], {t, -10, 10, 0.4}];
Export["fade.gif", fade]
```

#### Highlight

```
cutoff = 4;
highlight = Table[
   Graphics[{
     Thick, Circle[{t, 0}, 2], 
     Style[Circle[{t, 0}, Max[Abs[1.5*t], 2]], Red, Thick, 
      Opacity[If[Abs[t] < cutoff, 1, 0]]],
     Text[
      Style[If[t < 0, "|0〉", 
        "|1〉"], 32], {t, 0}],
     Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[White], 
     Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}], Text[Style["X", 64]]
     }, PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-5, 5}}], {t, -10, 10, 0.4}];
Export["highlight.gif", highlight]
```

Comment: Thanks so much - these will be cool to play around with. +1. =)